# How to link files to package explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I know there is a way to tell the editor window in Eclipse to link to the corresponding files. Say when you're on a file in the editor, it would be located in its corresponding project in the Package Explorer.

It shouldn't take more than enabling one option, but I am not able to find out where it is. 
It's a very handy thing which avoids confusion as to which file belongs to which project, if you have files with the same name in multiple projects.

Could anyone tell me where the option is located and how I can enable it again?

Comment: do you need to implement the feature in an rcp application, or just switch it on inside eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package explorer has an icon named 'Link with editor'. You can locate this way your currently editing file in Package Explorer view.

[image]

Alternatively, when you are editing, you may press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and choose Package Explorer to locate your file in Package Explorer.